# How to use Jquery Multiselect plugin on selected controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have created a user control which shows dropdown with check boxes. All works fine but when i use this control on my asp.net page, it effects other dropdown controls.

I don't want to effect other controls on my web page.

I have tried adding inline multi select style on user control but no luck, other controls are still effected.

**User Control**

```
            <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ucMultiSelect.ascx.vb" Inherits="ucMultiSelect" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <style type="text/css">
        .ui-multiselect { padding:2px 0 2px 4px; text-align:left }
        .ui-multiselect span.ui-icon { float:right }
        .ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes input { position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; left:-9999px; }
        .ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { padding:5px !important }

        .ui-multiselect-header { margin-bottom:3px; padding:3px 0 3px 4px }
        .ui-multiselect-header ul { font-size:0.9em }
        .ui-multiselect-header ul li { float:left; padding:0 10px 0 0 }
        .ui-multiselect-header a { text-decoration:none }
        .ui-multiselect-header a:hover { text-decoration:underline }
        .ui-multiselect-header span.ui-icon { float:left }
        .ui-multiselect-header li.ui-multiselect-close { float:right; text-align:right; padding-right:0 }

        .ui-multiselect-menu { display:none; padding:3px; position:absolute; z-index:10000; text-align: left }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes { position:relative /* fixes bug in IE6/7 */; overflow-y:auto }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { cursor:default; display:block; border:1px solid transparent; padding:3px 1px }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label input { position:relative; top:1px }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes li { clear:both; font-size:0.9em; padding-right:3px }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label { text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid }
        .ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label a { display:block; padding:3px; margin:1px 0; text-decoration:none }

        /* remove label borders in IE6 because IE6 does not support transparency */
        * html .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { border:none }


        </style>


        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo</title>
        <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.multiselect.css" />--%>
        <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />--%>
        <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/prettify.css" />--%>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/prettify.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>





        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("select").multiselect();
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body id="test">

            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="1"></asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>


            </body>
        </html>
```

**asp.net Page**

```
        <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <%@ Register src="ucMultiSelect.ascx" tagname="selectionCtrl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="1"></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <div>
            <uc1:selectionCtrl ID="selectionCtrl1" runat="server" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information to allow us to assist you? - How is your custom control built?  What specific "changes" to other drop downs are you seeing?  Do you have a jsFiddle sample you can use for illustration?

Comment: First drop down control should look like a normal asp.net control instead it looks same as my user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user control not clean should include only the part of required markup, as you placed the usercontrol in body part of `aspx page` it shouldn't include `html, head, body` tags.

**Change UserControl like below** observe that I've used selector div id = `testUserControl` while binding multiselect `$("#testUserControl select").multiselect();` This will scoped to only div#testUserControl section, you can apply similar logic wherever you want.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ucMultiSelect.ascx.vb" Inherits="ucMultiSelect" %>
<!--Below jquery api resources you can include in Master or Main page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<div id="testUserControl">
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#testUserControl select").multiselect({
            noneSelectedText: "Select Options" //here you can set "noneSelectedText" that you want
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How can i set the noneSelectedText from asp.net page?

Comment: I updated the answer with `noneSelectedText` option. If you want to set it from aspx page then move script block to aspx page .

Comment: I have tried moving the script block to aspx page but its not working. Could you please provide one example. Thanks

Comment: make sure that no list item selected, are you able to see the "Select Options" when you uncheck all

Comment: i had some issues with updatepanel , so i moved script to Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() and its working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: This answer is flippin' **epic**.  4 days wasted trying to do this, and this answer worked perfectly.